# How to implement search Venue through FourSquare API in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, foursquare

I display the nearby venues by Foursquare as per following `Github` code. It works fine.

[GitHUb Code](https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/Foursquare-API-v2)

But I want to implement the search API of Foursquare for venue search.

I already checked the Search API Documentation But I can not find any how can I implement this API.

Help me to solve this..

Answer (score -1):

If you take a look at the [Foursquare2 class](https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/Foursquare-API-v2/blob/master/Foursquare2/Foursquare2.h), there are a bunch of `searchVenues` methods that can achieve what you want.